# jqPlot line graph legends appearing below the graph

Tags: jquery, jqplot

My jqPlot line graph legends(1111,1112,1114) are appearing below the graph despite specifying the rendering option as "insidegrid".

I am not sure where is the problem. Here is my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdev/Y7FpV/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that you have not included `jquery.jqplot.css` in your code. Link to it and legend renders inside the grid. Here is updated jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nonocut/phRJx/